# Changing the Parameter in Linear Programing, Changes the Solution to the Dual

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider a linear optimization problem such that the RHS of the constraints depends on a parameter $a$, as in $$Ax=b+ae_j$$
Here $e_j$ is a unit vector in the direction of $x_j$.

Suppose that for some $a_0\in[\alpha,\beta]$ we have solved the problem using the tableau version of the simplex algorithm, and that the value of objective function does not change $\forall a\in[\alpha,\beta]$.

Assume our initial basis is given by the matrix $B$. Then $B^{-1}$ and $c_B$ can be found in the final tableau.

Now consider the dual problem. For $a=a_0$, we know that an optimal solution is $y^T=c_B^TB^{-1}$. Does this solution stay optimal $\forall a\in[\alpha,\beta]$?

Comment: Constrictions=constraints? And with the RHS, do you mean to say that the $b_i$'s are altered or that a variable is added to the already existent $x_i$'s in the constraints?

Comment: I mean that $b_i$ is altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The optimal z-row is represented in matrix-notation as follows: $z^*=c_BB^{-1}b + (c_N - c_BB^{-1}A_N)x_N$. So what it means that the objective value is not altered by the addition of $ae_j$ is that $c_BB^{-1}b=c_BB^{-1}(b+ae_j)$. Now see whether this means that $y^T$ is affected by the addition of $ae_j$ or not.

Comment: $y^T=c_B^TB^{-1}$ and therefore stays unaffected. Isn't that so?

Comment: I am not sure whether I am doing this correctly, so please don't take my word. But I would say that the fact that $c_BB^{-1}b=c_BB^{-1}(b+ae_j)$ holds, must mean that $c_BB^{-1}$ has changed, because it clearly doesn't hold that $b=b+ae_j$. Hence, $y^T$ would then not remain unaffected. However, as I said, I am absolutely not sure whether I am correct. I mainly posted my answer to hopefully get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with one parameter in objective function is solved by Simplex method, and dual problem  is converted to the problem with one parameter in constrict, and  is solved by Dual Simplex method. I have improved Simplex method and Dual Simplex method to solve parametric linear programming problem.